# Ballerina import from local package

Tags: ballerina

I have a ballerina project structure as below

```
/  <- project root
|
 - my.foo <- first package
      |
       - FooFunctions.bal <- Some .bal file
|
 - my.bar <- second package
      |
       - BarFunctions.bal <- Another .bal file
```

Note how package namespaces are used. They have `.` in the middle. Now let's say I have following simple **BarFunction.bal**

```
public function someName() returns int {
  return 10;
}
```

How shall I refer and use **someName** from **FooFunctions.bal** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both 'my.foo' and 'my.bar' modules are from the same project, you don't need to provide the organization-name when defining the import statement.

According to your scenario if you want to use 'someName()' function which is in 'my.bar' module in 'my.foo' you can simply do the following in 'FooFunctions.bal':

```
import my.bar; 

public function main() {   
  // i will have the value returned from 'someName()' function
  int i = bar:someName(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Documents lacks clear cut example on this.

Answer (score 2):

Official docs on packaging can be found from this [link](https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-structure-ballerina-code/#packages).

In simple terms [as of Ballerina 0.982 version], you can import **my.bar** package inside **my.foo** packages's any `.bal` file like below,

```
import ballerina/io;
import <org-name>/my.bar;

public function main(string... args) {
    io:println(bar:someName());
}
```

Where you replace the `<org-name>` from your project's root level **Ballerina.toml** file's `org-name` value. And note how `bar` is used to refer functions coming from **my.bar** package. This is highlighted in Ballerina document as below,

> Identifiers are either derived or explicit. The default identifier is either the package name, or if the package name has dots `.` include, then the last word after the last dot.

Furthermore, you may choose an identifier for package you import. For example, I can identify `<org-name>/my.bar` as `barimport` with following syntax,

```
import ballerina/io;
import <org-name>/my.bar as barimport;  # Now we refer import as barimport

public function main(string... args) {
    io:println(barimport:someName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I presume that "BarFunctions.bal" and "BarFunction.bal" are the same. If so, you can import "my.foo" module to "BarFunctions.bal" bal file as below:

`import my.foo;`

You dont need the organization name of the module as they are from the same project.